# Rails: return capitalized string from model

Tags: oop, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

In Rails 4, I have an attribute in my model. Let's say `Dog.name`, what code do I need to always return `Dog.name.capitalize`, instead of the database value?

For example in C# I would do `public string Name {get { return this.capitalize}; set; }`. How would I do that in Ruby?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain and undo your down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model override getter

```
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title
    self[:title].capitalize
  end
```

see [RailsStyleGuide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#read-attribute)  on reading attrs