# Default reader for ActiveRecord Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, overriding, reader

Is there any default reader method for ActiveRecord such that whenever I fetch a value from the DB this reader method will be called?(**Property.last.name** or **Student.first.course**). I want to override this method in such a way that if the data type is a string then convert it to uppercase. I don't want to add separate getters in each model for each column.

For ex:

```
def reader(column)
  column.upcase if column.is_a? String
end
```

Comment: is this one help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500898/rails-return-capitalized-string-from-model

Comment: Thanks. But if I add a new field I need to add a new getter which is not what I wanted. I want a default getter method that will be applicable for all the fields which can be overridden.

Comment: it might be possible to set this at the database connection level, depending on your database type.  what database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read#read_attribute` that returns the value after it has been typecasted. So monkey-patching (or refining) this method might give you what you want - all strings values will be transformed.

*But I'd seriously reconsider this approach in general*: all the data transformations should be explicit and visible if you don't want to shoot own leg.

It doesn't mean you cannot avoid redefining getters manually. For example, you can do smth. like this (disclaimer: quick and dirty example):

```rb
module TransformValues
  def transform(*attributes_to_transform, transformer: nil, &block)
    attributes_to_transform.each do |attribute_name|
      define_method attribute_name do
        case transformer = (block || transformer)
        when Proc
          transformer.call(self[attribute_name])
        when Symbol
          self[attribute_name].__send__(transformer)
        else
          self[attribute_name]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# and then

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend TransformValues
  transform :first_name, :last_name, transformer: :upcase
  transform :whatever do |val|
    do_smth_with(val)
  end
  # etc
end
```

In this case all your transformations stay more or less explicit without tons of manually written boilerplate. If all you need is just upcased strings, all this can be seriously reduced to just smth. like

```rb
module UpcaseAttributes
  def always_upcase(*attributes_to_transform)
    attributes_to_transform.each do |attribute_name|
      define_method attribute_name do
        case value = self[attribute_name]
        when String
          value.upcase
        else
          value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend UpcaseAttributes
  always_upcase :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But will this work for self.read or self.read_attribute?